# Build definitions containing AgentScope, FindMatchingFiles and IEnumerable<string>

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow, build-definition

I have a builddefinition in VS 2010 containing both the AgentScope and FindMatchingFiles activities. A also have defined a IEnumerable variable to hold the result from the FindMatchingFiles activity, and have set the Result to this variable.

When running the build it fails with:

> Type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' not visible. If the type is local, please set the LocalAssembly field in XamlReaderSettings.

This error occurs when the workflow reaches the AgentScope activity.

Here is the oddity:

1. When removing the variable from the FindMatchinFiles.Result (the variable still exist in the workflow) the error does not occur
2. When removing the AgentScope, the error does not occur.
3. Only in the described combination this error occurs.

I have reproduced this error by having a workflow with no more activities than the above described.

I need both the FindMatchingFile and the AgentScope, does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of your FindMatchingFiles Result variable.

[image: Checking scope of workflow variable]